# Filter similar rows based on timestamp as index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe with timestamp as index. I want to filter out the rows with similar timestamp and print it out. For example,

```
                        Value_1  Value_2
timestamp                                           
2022-03-22 17:31:02     23        30    
2022-03-22 17:31:02     25        40
2022-03-22 17:31:04     24        0.2   
2022-03-22 17:31:05     21        90    
2022-03-22 17:31:05     20        0.1
```

I want to filter out the rows with similar timestamps as shown below.

```
                        Value_1  Value_2
timestamp                                           
2022-03-22 17:31:02     23        30    
2022-03-22 17:31:02     25        40
2022-03-22 17:31:05     21        90    
2022-03-22 17:31:05     20        0.1
```

I tried using `melt` and `groupby`. It does not give me the desired results. Could someone help me with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False`(meaning if there is a duplicate value then mark all occurrence of that duplicate value to `True`)

```
df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

---

```
                     Value_1  Value_2
timestamp                            
2022-03-22 17:31:02       23     30.0
2022-03-22 17:31:02       25     40.0
2022-03-22 17:31:05       21     90.0
2022-03-22 17:31:05       20      0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `groupby` + `filter`:

```
filtered_df = df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_df
                     Value_1  Value_2
timestamp                            
2022-03-22 17:31:02       23     30.0
2022-03-22 17:31:02       25     40.0
2022-03-22 17:31:05       21     90.0
2022-03-22 17:31:05       20      0.1
```